# learning curve and validation curve in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a Neural Network to study one problem with a continuous output variable. A schematic representation of the neural network used is described below

[Schematic representation of neural network: input layer size = 1; hidden layer size = 8; output layer size = 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0eSI.jpg)

I am trying to understand the learning curve (error vs. number of training samples) and validation curve (error vs. regularization parameter lambda).

[Learning curves (lambda = 0.01, and lambda = 10) and validation curve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk2Ro.jpg)

I am relatively new with machine learning and I was wondering if someone could give me some advice on the analysis of these results. Do you think the learning curve looks ok for lambda = 0.01? Regarding the validation curve, do you also observe a minimum close to \lambda = 0.01? Would you recommend to increase the number of hidden layer?

Thanks in advance,

d

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your lambda=10 graph, I believe your learning rate is too large, because the error from training batch should be smaller than error from validation batch.

The curve with lambda=0.01 seems more plausible, but the training error curve is not significantly improving.

I would suggest that you do a step-wise reduction in value of lambda with respect to your cost value. This way you keep adjusting the lambda as your neural network learns.